# How can I reduce the size of an Angularjs site using Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

*How can I reduce the size of an Angularjs site using Google Closure Compiler?* I have a site on Angularjs 1.8. x, but I want to compile it using Closure. How can this be done? If there are ready-made examples and demos?

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and core components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can say much about closure compiler, but you can also checkout below optimizations for angular1.x:

**Lazy Loading** - Allows dynamic loading for js files. So the app's size is significantly reduced

**Webpack Bundling** - Allows minification / uglification of your code.

Comment: closure compiler, please